# Why IndexError when popping or deleting by index?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

Can you tell me why I have to surround this `if` in the try/except statement?
This method raises IndexError when I call the function with list in which last element is the same as other element in list. When the last element shows only once in a list, no IndexError is raised.

```
def unique(n):
    for i in range(len(n) - 1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            try:
                if n[i] == n[j]:
                    n.pop(i)
            except:
                pass
    return n

>>unique([1, 2, 3, 2, 4])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>unique([1, 2, 3, 4, 2])
IndexError
```

Without try/except in `if` statement:

```
>>print n[i]
2
>>n.pop(i)
IndexError
>>del n[i]
IndexError
```

Also surrounding `n.pop(i)` with try/except doesn't work, I had to surround whole `if` with it. Why?

Comment: Did you really execute `print n[i]` directly followed by `n.pop(i)` without doing anything in between?

Comment: You're in interpreter mode and you specified your own `i` outside of the function.

Comment: @jotto What is the final goal you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @fixxxer my goal is to understand why IndexError is raising. Well, now i do.

Comment: This is a perfect example of when and why you shouldn't let errors pass silently. Instead of letting them literally `pass`, put a `print()` in there to see which index you're trying to access (the problem is obviously in the `if` statement and not the `pop()` call) and the length of the `list` at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the iterable as you iterate over it, which is fundamentally wrong and can lead to undefined behavior. The behavior in this is that you are modifying the list length without informing the iterator of the change. The number of iterations will still be equal to the original length of list, but the actual number of elements could be lower (could, if there were no duplicates).

Accessing index that is not present in Python typically raises IndexError. Your try/except block will suppress that, but the iteration will still continue over the original length.

Possible solution is actually using a set, that will handle the uniqueness for you:

```
def unique(n):
    return list(set(n))
```

Or, keeping your iterative solution, create an empty list or copy of the list that you will assign your result to. To reduce the time complexity, the uniques can be stored as a dict where assigning a value is constant time:

```
def unique(n):
    uniques = {}

    for i in range(len(n) - 1, -1, -1):
        uniques[n[i]] = n[i]

    return list(uniques.keys())
```

If you care about the order of the appearance of the keys, OrderedDict can come in handy.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def unique(n):
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(n))
```

Comment: Except order will not necessarily be preserved, try: `[i for i in lst if lst.count(i) == 1]`

Comment: @mpolednik I really don't get it. I don't want the answer how to take unique values (BTW. I want to keep an order of values, which can be easily achieved by: OrderedDict.fromkeys(n)).
So you mean that i delete last element of list, and still while the 'i' has not iterated i am trying to access last element which is not in list, right? But why does it work when i surround whole if in try/except statement?

Comment: Change last code to -> OrderedDict.fromkeys(n) this is shorter.

Comment: When modifying the iterable in iteration, the iterator is not properly informed of the change and will go through the whole length before modification. That means you'll eventually (if duplicates are present) try to access an index that doesn't exist anymore. This raises IndexError - try/catch block will catch this for remaining keys, therefore it won't be raised to it's parent context. Edited the post to contain the explanation and OrderedDict.fromkeys(n).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe your

```
>>print n[i]
2
>>n.pop(i)
IndexError
```

demonstration. Anyway, instead of try/except, you can also just break the inner loop when you have found out that index `i` contains a duplicate and have removed it. After all, that's the only job of the inner loop. And then you also don't get the error, which precisely comes from continuing and trying to access `n[i]` after you already removed it.

```
def unique(n):
    for i in range(len(n) - 1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            if n[i] == n[j]:
                n.pop(i)
                break
    return n
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. You are right. Now i get it. This try/except was working on further loops, not that one that was deleting element.

Comment: @jotto Good :-). Still wondering whether your print+pop demonstration was real, though. Did that really happen like that? Because I don't think it can.